# reduce a list of string values by similarity score

Tags: python, machine-learning, categorical-data, sentence-similarity

I am facing a machine learning problem; Learning data consists of numeric, categorical and dates. I started training only based on numerics and dates (that I converted to numeric using epoch, week day, hours and so...). Apart from a poor score, performance are very well (seconds of training on one million entry).

The problem is with categoricals which most many values up to thousands.

Values consist of equipment brands, comments and so, and are humanly entered, So I assume there are much resemblances. I can sacrifice a bit of real world representation through data (hense score) for feasibility (training time).

Programming challenge: I came up with this from this [nice performance analysis](https://gist.github.com/amboar/fd3703950960cc8da826)

```
import difflib

def gcm1(strings):
    clusters = {}
    co = 0
    for string in (x for x in strings):
        if(co % 10000 == 0 ):
            print(co)
        co = co +1    
        if string in clusters:
            clusters[string].append(string)
        else:
            match = difflib.get_close_matches(string, clusters.keys(), 1, 0.90)
            if match:
                clusters[match[0]].append(string)
            else:
                clusters[string] = [ string ]
    return clusters

def reduce(lines_):
    clusters = gcm1(lines_)
    clusters = dict( (v,k) for k in clusters for v in clusters[k] )
    return [clusters.get(item,item) for item in lines_]
```

Example of this is like:

```
reduce(['XHSG11', 'XHSG8', 'DOIIV', 'D.OIIV ', ...] 
=> ['XHSG11', 'XHSG11', 'DOIIV', 'DOIIV ', ...]
```

I am very bound to Python so I couldn't get other C implemented code running.
Obviously, the function difflib.get_close_matches in each iteration is the most greedy.

**Is there an better alternative? or a better method of my algorithm?**

As I said on million entries, on let's say 10 columns, I can't even estimate when the algorithm stops (more than 3 hours and still running on my 16 gigs of RAM and i7 4790k CPU)

Data is like (extract):

```
    Comments:  [nan '1er rdv' '16H45-VE' 'VTE 2016 APRES 9H'
     'ARM : SERENITE DV. RECUP.CONTRAT. VERIF TYPE APPAREIL. RECTIF TVA SI NECESSAIRE']
    422227 different values

    MODELE_CODE:  ['VIESK02534' 'CMA6781031' 'ELMEGLM23HNATVMC' 'CMACALYDRADELTA2428FF'
     'FBEZZCIAO3224SVMC']
    10206 values

    MARQUE_LIB:  ['VIESSMANN' 'CHAFFOTEAUX ET MAURY' 'ELM LEBLANC' 'FR BG' 'CHAPPEE']
    167 values 
... more columns
```

Comment: Please clarify what *exactly* is your *question*.

Comment: any better performance idea or alternative on the function I'm using. sticking with Python

Comment: Kindly edit & update your post to explicitly include this

Comment: Where are the strings in `strings` coming from? Would you be open to use TfidfVectorizer and then compute the cosine similarity of the tokens of (words or chars) of the strings? If so, we can probably write a solution if you provide some mock examples of the documents on which you are working. The approach you have selected does not look very typical of machine learning.

Comment: @DanielR.  Any other method is welcome. Apart from comments who are whole phrases (short), other columns are not more that three words long.

Comment: I would do this: `1)` join all strings together, row-wise `2)` vectorize all joint rows with either CountVectorizer or TfidfVectorizer `3)` If you have reason to believe that some kind of grouping exists among them, feed the vectorised strings to a clusterer to compute the centers of those clusters `4)` Compute the cosine similarity of the centers of the clusters, if previously identified, or the pairwise cosine similarity of the vectors output by the vectorizers. But you have to pass a sample of your data in a format that can be easily copied and pasted into code if you want help from SO.